# Calculate running total with over(partition by order by) within update statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a running total of revenues over product subgroups with discounts given ordered ascending.

I have used the following query

```
Update Z_Discount_Tool1 Set Cum_Net_Revenue_Discount = 
(Select Sum([Umsatz_Netto]) Over (Partition by [WUGR_act] Order by [Discount] From Z_Discount_Tool1)
```

However, I receive the following error message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I can't find the error in my code. So any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the syntax, I added the sql-server tag.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like SQL Server.  You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select dt.*,
             Sum([Umsatz_Netto]) Over (Partition by [WUGR_act] Order by [Discount]) as new_Cum_Net_Revenue_Discount
      from Z_Discount_Tool1 dt
     )
Update toupdate
     Set Cum_Net_Revenue_Discount = new_Cum_Net_Revenue_Discount;
```